# Make "Top Questions" on the top of new UI into a link to refresh the page

Tags: feature-request

"Top Questions" seems to not do anything at the moment. I know that I often browse SO by refreshing the questions page just to see what comes up. Can we make Top Questions into a link that loads the latest data for the currently selected questions page?